# The word for a date that’s not definite yet

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word for a date that has to be fixed?

> The party’s ______ date is April 26.

Comment: You can try "target".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***[Tentative](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/it/dizionario/inglese/tentative)*** is the word you want, meaning not fixed, uncertain, or provisional. A tentative date for an event is a current best guess, which is not certain and may or may not change later on.

Comment: What's wrong with **provisional**?

Comment: @KateBunting Provisional can also mean temporary. Tentative was a word designed for this purpose and nothing else so is the most appropriate choice.

Comment: @uberhaxed - Designed by whom? More than one dictionary gives the two words as synonyms. and _provisional_ is certainly the word I commonly see used in this context.